# How can I edit the sql commands of symfony doctrine when updating a schema?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, symfony, symfony4

I have the following error when I'm trying to update my database schema :

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1833 Cannot change column 'IdEcole': used in a foreign key constraint 'appartient_ibfk_2' of table 'tuteure.appartient'
```

However, I don't have anything that make the `IdEcole` AUTO_INCREMENT (in database or in my Entitites, only in the migrations.

When I execute the following line `php bin/console doctrine:schema:update --dump-sql` I have the following response :

```
ALTER TABLE Ecole CHANGE IdEcole IdEcole INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
```

**So how can I edit this line to delete it ? Where is this line stored and where it comes from ?**

Comment: The error message is very clear **table 'tuteure.appartient' ** has a **foreign key** namend **'appartient_ibfk_2' of ** that references column  **IdEcole** of the table IdEcole

Comment: It comes from Doctrine identifying differences between the actual state of the database and what you've configured through code. How are you configuring your entities, using annotations?

Comment: However i don't have any commands that override the constraint in IdEcole

Comment: @El_Vanja I didn't manually configured my entites, I import my existing sql file

Comment: Even if they're generated, the information is written somewhere. Are there annotations in your entities or is it written in an XML file? Whichever it is, check if your `IdEcole` has a `GeneratedValue` specified somewhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally find where the problem cames from :

Symfony's Doctrine use migrations to update your code and your database.
So, in my last migration file (in `src/Migrations` a file with a name like `VersionNUMBER.php`).

I edit this file which contains two method : `up` and `down` and I just delete the line :

```sql
ALTER TABLE Ecole CHANGE IdEcole IdEcole INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL;
```

And make a simple :

```
php bin/console doctrine:migrations:execute NUMBERVERSION
```

Where **NUMBERVERSION** is my number (the name of the `migration` file and the class)

And after :

```
php bin/console doctrine:schema:update
```